# Recover an image from an android to send to server

Tags: android, json, file, kotlin, flask

I am currently working on an android application and I would like to add a file system to send images. But I don't know how to get an image from the local storage of an android, nor how to send it to a server. I am currently using a flask server to retrieve JSON files, and I don't know if retrieving images would be possible with this kind of server.

Would you have any clue how to retrieve a file on a button press and send it to a server please?

Comment: please show us what you have tried

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this library to pick from local storage and upload it to the server with ease

https://github.com/gotev/android-upload-service

Answer (score 1):

At this point, it doesn't matter what server you use as long as you can retrieve data.
You can do it using [Retrofit](https://github.com/square/retrofit). For detailed instruction, check [This](https://medium.com/android-news/working-with-retrofit-825d30348fe2) medium post!